# Retrieving strings in Parse

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve two strings from my Parse Customers class. I want to compare these strings (usernameAdmin, and passwordAdmin respectively) with the input field entered by the user, and if they matched it will take them to a specific page.

I am taking this approach for a particular reason, and would appreciate feedback.

```
    $scope.logIn = function(form) {

  var Customer = Parse.Object.extend("Customers");

    parseAdminUsername = Customer.get('usernameAdmin');
    parseAdminPassword =    Customer.get('passwordAdmin');



    if (form.lusername == parseAdminUsername && form.lpassword == parseAdminPassword) {

      window.location = 'adminSelect.php'
    } else {
    alert('error');
}

  };
```

The html code looks as follow:

```
<form role="form"  ng-show="scenario == 'Sign up'">
<h4 id="wrongCredentials"></h4>
<input id="signupformItem" ng-model="user.lusername" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"> <br>
<input id="signupformItem" ng-model="user.lpassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder=" Password"> <br>

<br>
<button id="signupbuttonFinal" ng-click="logIn(user)" class="btn btn-danger"> Sign In</button>

</form>
```

I receive the following error on console:

```
 undefined is not a function
    at Object.$scope.logIn
```

below is the line

```
parseAdminUsername = Customer.get('usernameAdmin');
```

Comment: Can't think of any valid reason at all to ever have password sent to the client. Parse has a roles based user management system , use that instead

Comment: this is because I wanted to seperate between users and admin. Where parse.user stores all my user information, and I created a seperate class just to deal with admin, but the problem with Parse is that you cant have two user class

Comment: Why can't you use roles?

Comment: Yes, you should use roles for that

Comment: Because I feel this way it would be more organized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using Parse in built users instead of creating a separate object and then you would use `Parse.User.logIn`.

If you were to use your table instead. `Customer.get('usernameAdmin')` is used to return a field after you have performed a query to return records/s. You are best to perform a find query to check the username and password like so:

```
var Customer = Parse.Object.extend("Customers");
var query = new Parse.Query(Customer);
query.equalTo("usernameAdmin", form.lusername);
query.equalTo("passwordAdmin", form.lpassword);

query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    if (results.length > 0) {
        window.location = 'adminSelect.php';
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

I'd recommend not to use `window` and instead $window so that you can unit test your code. Better yet use angular routing and create a Single page app.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and your response was incredibly helpful. The reason why I am not using Parse.User.Login is because I created two different classes - Users and Admin, where Parse.User is used to store user date and this one for admin (you cant have two user special classes in parse). One question though, on the adminSelect page, I would only want those who have succesfully login to be able to view it with angular and parse.user i can do   $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

Comment: See, this is the problem with what you have chosen to do. It won't be very secure because you will need to store if the user is logged in on the server and not the client. To do that you would have to write Parse server side code. You should instead be using Parse inbuilt user as it will handle this for you. If you want to have different roles then use https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#roles. There is an example there where there is an Administrator role

Comment: I agree, but the amount of admin is limited, and there will no registration process for admin as I will manually add them, and given that there is no registration having access to their password is important as they are handpick, and only I have access to parse. I am aware roles, but I feel its better organised that way. For the admin page  to see wheter or not the user has login I was thinking of workaround l

Comment: Then you would just manual create the admin user and assign them the admin role. It's actually not difficult. You have made it much harder for you in trying to not use what is built in to Parse

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but how would i ensure that only that admin user can login to that page cause below is my code for login (user)  Parse.User.logIn(form.lusername, form.lpassword, {
      success: function(user) {
  window.location = 'userinterfaceSelect.php'
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
   
     var div = document.getElementById("wrongCredentials");
    div.textContent = "The email or/and the password you have entered is invalid";

      }
    });

Comment: What's the admin page for?

Comment: to manage user information such as send a message to all users in the system (if you could kindly assist me with that as well I will be unbelievably grateful), and other task that shouldn't be allowed by the user. I just do not want any user who register to be able to access that page but only certain user

Comment: It's very complicated to implement a send message to all users. You don't actually need roles. What you can do is lock down the security of the data to specific users (or roles) using Parse security, so you can lock down the restricted data to the admin user, so if someone tries to get the data who doesn't have access it would error and then you would display an unauthorised message.

Comment: oh okay thanks for your suggestions. As for sending message to all users, i dont think its as complex. I know its possible with push, but thats only works with mobile devices. I am thinking of when you hit submit, that message will be stored in all users, and from on the user page, Il have it where it pulls information from that parse column (message), but my problem is not pulling, but storing information to all users. I have laid it out better at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131355/message-all-users-parse

Comment: I guess it depends. If you want to actually push the message, then it can get complicated. Your solution is not really push

Comment: Yeah i guess i poorly explain myself. I do not want to replicate the push for mobile, and its not exactly push. More like on the user side interface, i can easily setup where it constantly grabs information from that column, if no information is found there than nothing would be displayed, my main issue is storing that information to all users as an array (could have multiple message)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69532/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-jon).