# Message all users Parse

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parse-platform

I know push notification works well for mobile (Android,iOS, Windows), but for a web based (using javascript), I am trying to figure out a way to message all users.

I am brainstorming the following:

```
    $scope.messageAll = function(form) {
var user = not sure what to put here
    user.set("subject", form.subject);
        user.set("message", form.message);
          user.save();


  };
```

I am not sure if I am in the right path or if this proper code.
Let me know, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need to explain use case more thoroughly. Can't push something to a browser that isn't connected by a socket

Comment: since you marked your question as angular i am referring 2 links https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io  and https://github.com/mbenford/ngSocketIO